# Dynamic filtration in tree hirarchy

Tags: 7

I want a tree structure like below:
`-parent1
 +child 1
 +child 2
 -child 3
  +sub child 1
+parent2
+parent3`
...
 and when a user click on lets say "child1" then items in views related to them will be filtered.
How can I achieve this?Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module. You can build your tree structure with Drupal taxonomy.

Unlike Hierarchical select this module provides a simple widget for taxonomy terms only. As an addition Simple hierachical select works as Views exposed filter.

Comment: Thanku for replying ankit, yes i am using this one, I created the taxonomy for the above hierarchy.Now i have one view of a specific content type, I add a field there and select "simple hierarchical select" in widget type. And also select the specific taxonomy term during adding content to that content type. But that hierarchical structure is not displaying on my page?

Comment: I also added the filter criteria "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; <em class="placeholder">Simple hierarchical select</em>) (or Unknown) | Settings"